# How to return only 1 item in an array in react using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently when user click on a particular topic it returns all the items in an array. However, I would like to pass the key and only return specific item within the object in the map function. I tried passing index as an argument but it doesn't seems to work.

```
var topicPages = [
    { 
        topic_no: '1',
        topic_page_no: '1',
        headline: 'Topic 1 headline', 
        description: 'Topic 1 description comes here...', 
        first_topic_page: true,
        last_topic_page: false
    },
    { 
        topic_no: '2',
        topic_page_no: '2',
        headline: 'Topic 2 headline', 
        description: 'Topic 2 description comes here...', 
        first_topic_page: false,
        last_topic_page: false
    },
    { 
        topic_no: '3',
        topic_page_no: '3',
        headline: 'Topic 3 headline', 
        description: 'Topic 3 description comes here...', 
        first_topic_page: false,
        last_topic_page: false
    },
    { 
        topic_no: '4',
        topic_page_no: '4',
        headline: 'Topic 4 headline', 
        description: 'Topic 4 description comes here...', 
        first_topic_page: false,
        last_topic_page: true
    }
];

var SelectedTopicPage = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.topicPages.map(function (topicPage) {
                    return (
                        <SelectedTopicPageMarkup headline={topicPage.headline} key={topicPage.topic_no}>
                            {topicPage.description}
                        </SelectedTopicPageMarkup> 
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var SelectedTopicPageMarkup = React.createClass({

    render: function() {    
        return (
            <div className="topics-page">
                <h1>{this.props.headline}</h1>
                <p>{this.props.children}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `find`, but it is not supported in all browsers. Use `reduce` instead of `map`:

```
var SelectedTopicPage = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        var selectedId = this.props.selectedId; // id what you need to find
        var topicPage = this.props.topicPages.reduce(function(topic, current) {
            return topic.topic_no == selectedId ? current : topic;
        }, undefined);

        return (
            <SelectedTopicPageMarkup headline={topicPage.headline} key={topicPage.topic_no}>
                {topicPage.description}
            </SelectedTopicPageMarkup>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Why `.reduce`? instead of `.filter`?

Comment: `.filter` will return an array, so you will need to get the first element of array, in my opinion `.reduce` much simplier if `find` is not available

Comment: but the question was [How to return only 1 item in an array] So I suppose he needs an array with one element. Anyway thank for explanation

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have already found what you were looking for but,
I saw this question but no answer, still.

You just need to define a variable outside mapping and while mapping, put an if condition to find what you looking for and then equalize the result to the variable outside.

Like,

```
    let tmpItem;
    this.state.newOrder.map((mapItem) => {
        if (mapItem.id == "99") {
            console.log(mapItem)
            tmpItem = mapItem;
        }
    });
```